# In eclipse it is showing value 1.8 is not a valid language level

Tags: java, drools

I am using drools project in eclipse luna, java 1.8, drools 5.4.0.
When i am opening drools file it is showing value '1.8' is not a valid language level.
what should i do?

Answer (score 10):

Late answer but posting anyway hoping it'll help someone.

Drop down the compliance level to Java7:
Project Properties> Java Compiler and Tick "Enable Project specific settings"
Select compiler compliance level to 1.7.

If your project is faceted may need to drop down the facet version as well.
Project Properties> Project Facets and select 1.7 for the row containing Java.

Comment: thanks it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Drop down the compliance level to Java7:

> Project Properties> Java Compiler and Tick "Enable Project specific settings" Select compiler compliance level to 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

its a bug with drools eclipse and java 8 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1078146