# eclipse value '1.8' is not a valid language level

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, jbpm

Im working with drools and Im getting this error when I want to open *.drl*  file

"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
value '1.8' is not a valid language level"

Im using

- eclipse
- JDK 1.8
- drools jbpm tool 5.3 final

Comment: Which eclipse are you using?

Comment: Every year there is a new major Eclipse version. What version do you use: "Luna" "Mars" "Neon" or "Oxygen"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In eclipse it is showing value 1.8 is not a valid language level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603747/in-eclipse-it-is-showing-value-1-8-is-not-a-valid-language-level/27603790). It looks like you need to specify compliance level 1.7.

Comment: it worked for me thanks @skomisa