# Eclipse Drools value 11 is not a valid language level

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

Using Eclipse and the Drools plugin, with my JDK set to Amazon Coretto 11, I get the following single error on each drl

value '11' is not a valid language level

I have seen plenty of similar issues for Java 8, where the solution is to drop down to Java 7.
E.g. [In eclipse it is showing value 1.8 is not a valid language level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603747/in-eclipse-it-is-showing-value-1-8-is-not-a-valid-language-level/27603790)

I can't see anything for Java 11 though, on here or Google. Does anyone know if this is a bug in the plugin?

If I drop the JDK for the project (Properties > Java Compiler) down to 8, I then get errors related to lambdas I have in the drl (which run fine).

It's a painful way to develop, any help appreciated.